# asp.net mvc ajax.begineform onsuccess event and model validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, jquery

Here are the codes

```
public class MyModel
{
   [Required]
   public string Title {get;set;}

}


public class MyController : Controller
{
     public ActionResult Post(MyModel model)
     {
          if (!ModelState.IsValid)
             return PartialView(model);

          return PartialView("SomeOtherView"); 
     }



}
```

Here is my View

```
   @model MyModel

   @using(Ajax.BeginForm("Post","My",new AjaxOptions{OnSuccess = "Sucess" }) {
         Html.Partial("Post",Model)

  }

<script>
 function Success(content)
 {
   $("#somediv").html(content);

 }


</script>
```

Now, when ModelState Dictionary has no error, everything goes well, but when there is some model validation error, I have no way to detect it in javascript. Can someone help here.

Regards
Parminder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to achieve this. One way is to have the server side send a proper HTTP code (500) in case of error:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    Response.StatusCode = 500;
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

and on the client subscribe for the `OnFailure` callback and handle the error case in a different function.